# In C# XML comments, can you detail the type a List<T> contains?

Tags: c#, sandcastle, xml-documentation

Currently I'm documenting Lists as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a <see cref="List{T}" /> of type <see cref="Person" />.
/// </summary>
public List<Person> ListExample()
{

}
```

The following does not seem to be interpreted by Sandcastle:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a <see cref="List{Person}" />.
/// </summary>
public List<Person> ListExample()
{

}
```

Any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: To the Person Class if you clicked on the Person part.

Comment: As an aside, you may be better off using HTML for `<T>` instead of `{T}` by using `&lt;T&gt;`.

Comment: Interesting Wai-Ha-Lee ... Why?